# Getting value of specific name tag

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I have this xml:

```
<ns0:data>
<ns0:row>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>F_DOCNUMBER</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>617271</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>DOCDATE</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>15685</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>DOCTYPE</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>1,999,152</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>INSUREDIDNUMBER</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>310794763</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>BATCHNAME</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>L1000024831310001</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
</ns0:row>
<ns0:row>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>F_DOCNUMBER</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>617284</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>DOCDATE</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>15685</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>DOCTYPE</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>1,999,403</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>INSUREDIDNUMBER</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>310794763</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>BATCHNAME</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>L1000024831320002</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
</ns0:row>
<ns0:row>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>F_DOCNUMBER</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>617283</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>DOCDATE</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>15685</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>DOCTYPE</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>1,999,235</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>INSUREDIDNUMBER</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>310794763</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
    <ns0:column>
        <ns0:name>BATCHNAME</ns0:name>
        <ns0:value>L1000024831320001</ns0:value>
    </ns0:column>
</ns0:row>
</ns0:data>
```

I need to get all the value tags which their name is "DOCTYPE".

Later I need to check and change their value.

How can I get this nodes?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `LINQ` to `XML` to get the required node this as

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("YourXmlFilePath");
XNamespace ns = "YourNameSpacegoesHere";

var query = from d in doc.Descendants(ns + "column")
            where d.Element(ns + "name").Value.ToString() == "DOCTYPE"                  
            select d;
```

now `query` has all your required nodes.